# DS.js JSON file format from CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I am trying to follow the DS.js sunburst example (see link below) where a csv is first converted to a JSON to display the graphic. I wanted to do the same on larger data but using JSON as csv is too cumbersome in my project. However I am unable to understand the mapping of the csv to JSON in this example. Is there a way to dump the JSON structure from the JS code? It is stored in a variable (json) like this:

```
d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
createVisualization(json);
```

http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see the structure directly in Chrome console (Ctrl + Shift + j) by adding **console.log(json)** :

```
d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  console.log(json);
  createVisualization(json);
});
```

If you want to be able to copy/paste the json structure you can use **console.log(JSON.stringify(json));** and copy/paste the output in console.